# How to use border radius with image on html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I have faced issue with **border-radius** on img tag in **html2canvas**. If somebody has solution for this please share.

Original html view
 [image: Original]

After converting to image using html2canvas
[image: after]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to describe your problem more precisely. It is not clear what kind of issue you are having exactly, please take time to update your question.

Comment: please include some code and explain your problem in more detail

Comment: Hi I put the image links. Please have a look.